# Django: ForeignKey and related_name

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Please help me to write model with ForeignKeys.

Table 1:

```
| ports | CREATE TABLE `ports` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`device_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`login` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
KEY `name` (`name`),
KEY `state` (`state`),
KEY `login` (`login`),
CONSTRAINT `ports_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES 
`switch` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Model for table 1:

```
class Ports(models.Model):
    device_id = models.ForeignKey('Switch', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ports'
```

Table 2:

```
| switch | CREATE TABLE `switch` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`addr` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`community` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ports` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`street_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `type` (`type`),
CONSTRAINT `switch_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `switch_types` (`id`)
)
```

Model for table 2:

```
class Switch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    community = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.ForeignKey('SwitchTypes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='type', blank=True, null=True)
    ports = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    street_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'switch'
```

When i run the server i get an error:

> ERRORS:
>
> api.Ports.device_id: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Ports.device_id' clashes with field name 'Switch.ports'.
>       HINT: Rename field 'Switch.ports', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Ports.device_id'.

I can not rename ports column in the Switch table in MySQL. Read-only.
What related_name of device_id field I should set? If I add related_name='+' all works without errors, but '+' disables mapping. 
Or I need to do something else?

Comment: `device = ForeignKey(... related_name='ports_of_device')`

Comment: Ivan Starostin Could you explain to me the error was due to the fact that field [device_id] has '_id' in the end?

Comment: `_id` is just not necessary. The error message was saying that field names and relation names got mixed in your app: like "switch.ports" is supposed to mean `Switch.ports` or `Ports.device->(relation=switch_ports)->Switch`? Something like that.

Comment: It is confusing to me as well: you have `ports` per `switch` as a list of records in `Ports` table and at the same time you have `ports` scalar field in `Switch` table. So which "ports" is correct? Django was being confused almost the same way: what is `switch.ports` out of two possible options?